# Vuex Store Unknown Getters with Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, getter, vuex, nuxt.js

I've almoust finished my app in Vuejs and now I decided to "rewrite" everything on Nuxt due to SSR :)
I almoust get everything but there is this getter thing I am not getting.. I can't make it around even though I tried so hard and I am not sure what I am missing.

I am using vuex module so my /store/categories.js looks like:

```
export const state = () =>  ({
  categories: [
    {
          name: 'category 1',
         id: '1'
         subcategories: [
        {
           name: 'Subcategory 1',
            id: '1.1'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'category 2',
      id: '2',
      subcategories: [
        {
          name: 'Subcategory 2',
          id: '1.1'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
export const getters = () => ({
filterCategory() {
    return state.categories
  },
})
```

This is a simple getter above and I can't even make this work..

And here is my posts/test.vue page:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ filter }} </p>
    <p>{{ mainCategories }} </p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'test',
  layout: 'test',
  data () {
    return {
      search: '',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      filter: 'categories/filterCategory'
    }),
    mainCategories () {
      return this.$store.getters['categories/filterpazari']
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: State and getters are not functions, they should be objects (`export const state = {...}`).

Comment: @Bert You saved my life :) I've seen that State have to bo a function, otherwise it won't work, so I thought getters should.. I tried everything else except not making getter a function. That works thnx

Answer (score 0):

Getters should be exported as objects not function.

As [Bert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38065/bert) already mentioned in the comment how to declare getters. But it was trouble some to find the solutions at first glance. So here is the formated answer.

```
const getters = {
  filterCategory: state => state.categories,
}

export default getters
```

*Credit to **[Bert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38065/bert)***